# Play HTTP Video in WKWebView on iOS 10

Tags: ios, html5-video, ios10, wkwebview, app-transport-security

I've read a lot about Apple's App Transport security policy, what is allowed and what is not.

I use javascript to request video data and read video in html5 video tag.
When I can I use https but it's not always possible.

In iOS 9 I used to enable "Allow Arbitrary Loads" and every thing was fine.
With iOS 10, this setting isn't available anymore and we can use "Allow Arbitrary Loads in Web Content" when working in WKWebView.

This should be my solution but it seems this doesn't allow html5 Videos loaded through http.

Here what I've tried so far:

All those settings are set in the info.plist file for my application, in the dictionary:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        ...
</dict>
```

**Arbitrary loads:**

```
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
```

This only worked in iOS9 and doesn't in iOS 10.

**Arbitrary loads in web view**

```
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
```

This enable all other http requests in WKWebView but not the video content.

**Manually set exception domains**

```
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.thedomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

This works and allows the video to be loaded. For now I use it during development but it's not suitable as I need to load video from multiple domain without knowing them in the first place.

**Arbitrary loads in media**

```
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia</key>
    <true/>
```

I'm not sure what this setting does. But using it didn't change anything and http video content is still not allowed.

So here I'm stuck. 
Did you make some test like that? did you experience the same thing?
And more important do you know any solution I should try ?

Comment: The AllowsArbitraryLoads setting is available in iOS 10.  You will just need to provide justification to Apple when you submit with the flag on.  If you submit before the end of the year, you won't need to provide justification.  However, after the 12/31/2016, any updates to the app submitted to the app store will require justification, and you'll be at the mercy of Apple's review process whether they accept the app.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Did I forget something ?

Comment: The `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInMedia` is set directly under the `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary, which is at the top level of your Info.plist?  Maybe a screenshot of your Info.plist would be helpful in spotting the issue.  Another option, which may or may not be feasible for you, would be to use a `SFSafariViewController` conditionally for iOS 9 and up.